# Don't submit all form fields

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project that I'm using stripe to handle payment processing, as part of this I've created a form for collecting card information, my problem is that I want to submit some of the data to be sent to my server (like name and email address), but other parts (the card details) I don't since they're processed by stripe so there's no point sending them to my server.

I'm not sure how I can do this though, since the input fields that I do and don't want to send are all mixed together, so I can't just wrap the parts I do want in the form tag and not the rest.

Is the a flag on a form field that I can set so that it isn't submitted with the form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you building the Stripe / credit card part of your form? With Checkout? With Elements? With an older version of Stripe.js? 

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
https://stripe.com/docs/elements

Comment: I'm creating the form with rails' form helpers.

Comment: You can submit all the fields, just add some controller logic to ignore the ones you're not using

Comment: Why don't you use Strong parameters of rails ?
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: How are you going to send the card details to Stripe if you don't submit them?

Comment: Stripe have a js handler that sends the card details to them, then returns a token which is then sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript or Ajax may be the best way

- Get values and trigger for differentes urls

Check this link: [send specific part of the form fields to server using ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580550/send-specific-part-of-the-form-fields-to-server-using-ajax)